# How to use unknown JSON key names as my table headers

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm using Laravel framework.

I've got a table with some JSON I want to iterate over, I've cast the table to an array. This is the format;

```
{"Height": "#m", "Width": "#m", "Weight": {"now": "#kg", "previous": "#kg"}}
```

My controller returns the view;

```
$person = Person::find($ID);
$data = $person->tableJson;
return view('person.person_details', compact('person', 'data'));
```

And in the view itself:

```
@foreach ($data as $value)
    Width: {{ $value->tableJson['Width'] }} <br>
    Height: {{ $value->tableJson['Height'] }} <br>
    Weight (now): {{ $value->tableJson['Weight']['now'] }} <br>
    Weight (previous): {{ $value->tableJson['Weight']['previous'] }} <br> 
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

I have that working. The thing is I want to replace the hard coded titles (Width, Height, etc) with the keys in the JSON itself. That way I can (hopefully) dynamically populate a table without knowing what the JSON contains.

Answer (score 1):

When looping your `$data` use actual keys in that:

```
$data = [0: ["Height" => "#m", "Width" => "#m", "Weight" => ["now" => "#kg", "previous" => "#kg"]]];

foreach ($data as row) {
    foreach ($row as $header => $val) {
        if (is_string($val)) {
            echo "{$header}: {$val}<br/>";
        } else {
            foreach ($val as $type => $subVal) {
                echo "{$header} ($type): {$subVal}<br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't seem to actually work without tweaking - but taking bits from it was helpful. It doesn't help in the case of a dynamic JSON either. Since you're making assumptions with the if else statement.